# Get One MembershipUser from MembershipUserCollection

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-membership

I have a membershipusercollection that I am trying to get one specific user from. Unfortunately I cannot user the `MembershipUser.GetUser()` method. So currently I have a collection of all membership users like so:

```
MembershipUserCollection mc = Membership.GetAllUsers();
```

What I would like to do is get one of these users by either login or email (doesn't matter which). I realize I can do a foreach loop on the collection and compare but I have to imagine there is a better way....

Thanks in advance...

For those curious why I cannot user the getuser method, lets just say it is because of sharepoint.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10662397

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
mc.Cast<MembershipUser>().SingleOrDefault(m => m.UserName == "username");
```

Comment: Do you mean like so:MembershipUser membershipuser = mc.Cast<MembershipUser>().SingleOrDefault(m => m.UserName == user.LoginName);

Answer (score 1):

`MembershipUser.GetUser()` is not a valid method instead `Membership.GetUser("johndoe")`.

```
var user = Membership.GetAllUsers()
    .Cast<MembershipUser>()
    .FirstOrDefault(m => m.Email == "john@doe.com" || m.UserName == "johndoe");
```

One thing you want to watch out is `GetAllUsers` retrieves all users from database.

Comment: technically you don't know what GetAllUsers() does, it depends on the implementation :)

Comment: @PauliØsterø There is only one override for `GetAllUsers` in membership provider. If you do not follow what the provider is initially intended, then I can't help it. :|

Comment: I'm just saying that there is no mention in the OP of which Membership Provider is in question, only some hints of some Sharepoint. So you can't implicitly say that the provider is using a database as store, it could be an in-memory representation of a result from a web service, for all that we know.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there is another way:

```
MembershipUser m = mc["username"];
```